# Ionic 4 routing url is showing the route without changing the page that should be displayed

Tags: angular, routes, ionic4

I having a problem in Ionic 4 routing.

Once a successful login, I need the user to be redirected to `/home` module using:

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('home')
```

I already imported `NavController` in the `constructor()` using:

```
private navCtrl: NavController
```

The `app-routing.module.ts` is like the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    loadChildren: './list/list.module#ListPageModule'
  },
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' 
  }
];
```

And at the `app.module.ts`, the bootstrap module is set as `LoginPage`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginPage],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule  
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [LoginPage]
})
```

When I run the mobile app, the url shown is:

```
http://localhost:8100/home
```

Which is weird, as it should be `http://localhost:8100` or `http://localhost:8100/login`.

The `HomePage` contains the side menu with the `router-outlet`:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
      <ion-img src="/assets/shapes.svg"></ion-img>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>Get Started</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>Welcome to Ionic</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>Now that your app has been created, you'll want to start building out features and components. Check out some of the resources below for next steps.</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-list lines="none">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Resources</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="book"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Ionic Documentation</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/scaffolding">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="build"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Scaffold Out Your App</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/structure">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="grid"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Change Your App Layout</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics">
        <ion-icon slot="start" color="medium" name="color-fill"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Theme Your App</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

P.S.:

1. I used `angular router` instead, and I had the same result.
2. `navCtrl.push()` is not available anymore in Ionic 4.

Comment: Just a comment: Stick to angular router, since this is what we use in ionic 4 :)

Comment: I used `this.router.navigateByUrl(...)` and had the same result @AJT_82

Comment: Well, I didn't look at the code so closely, just saw your `P.S` at the bottom :)

Comment: But looking at it more closely, you have specified if the route is `''` redirect to `home`. I guess you'd want to redirect to `login`, yes?

Comment: @AJT_82 I changed it to `Login` and I got an error of `LoginPage is declared in 2 NgModules`

Comment: Well, according to error you have declared LoginModule in two NgModules, should be in just one, check your modules.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the `ion-router-outlet` in `app.component.html` ?

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```